# Radiator bleed valve leaking after bleeding

Tags: radiator, leaking

After I bled our radiators this evening, one of the radiators is leaking out of the bleed valve. I can see water droplets forming very slowly on the valve and then dripping, perhaps a droplet every 30 seconds or so. I've tried tightening the screw again, of course, and it seems to be closed tightly.

We've put a bit of silicone over the valve and duct taped it on tightly, in the hope of closing it off for the time being. Any suggestions as to what the correct solution might be?

Comment: For future reference silicone is hardly ever the answer for a leaking valve. _*I say "hardly ever" because there_ might _be some situations I'm not aware of._

Comment: @FreeMan no doubt! it was bedtime, we were looking for the nearest thing at hand that could conform to and put a bit of pressure on the end of the vent tube, and there happen to be a little ball of silicone nearby. it's done the trick until we get around to a proper solution, at any rate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be a bit of rust trapped in the valve. I'd try flushing it again, maybe wiggling the valve stem back and forth a bit to encourage whatever it is to flush out, then close again and hope.

Failing that, the whole bleed valve can be unscrewed and a replacement installed...